# Moving XML text whilst filtering the node tree

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I'm trying to filter out empty font nodex from an HMTL doc that has been loaded into an XML doc.

My XML looks like this:

```
<root>
<font>
  <font color="#141414">
    <font>
      <font></font>
    </font><font></font><font> </font>(I need this text in the outer font)
  </font>
</font>
</root>
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
<root>
  <font color="#141414"> (I need this text in the outer font)</font>
</root>
```

Note the space from the inner font node has also been moved.

I wrote a console app using a recursive function found on Stack Overflow but it doesn't work. I can't use Linq to XML nor any third party libraries. I'm a bit lost.

This was my console app:

```html
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<root><font><font color=\"#141414\"><font><font></font></font><font></font><font> </font>(I need this text in the outer font)</font></font></root>");
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("root");
            RemoveEmptyFontTags(node.ChildNodes);
        }

        private static void RemoveEmptyFontTags(XmlNodeList nodes)
        {
            foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                RemoveEmptyFontTags(node.ChildNodes);
                if(node.Name.ToLower() == "font" && node.Attributes.Count == 0)
                {
                    node.ParentNode.InnerXml = node.InnerXml;
                }                
            }
        }
    }​
```